# How to trigger an Ansible task only if concerned directories are old enough (+30 days for example)?

Tags: directory, ansible

How to trigger an Ansible task only if concerned directories are old enough (+30 days for example)?

Want to do something like

```yaml
- name: backup biggest files 
  #get difference between currentdate & last backup
  register: age
```

I know I can get either a string or a defined on when clause but I don't know how to here.

My goal is, if `/mnt/backup.YYYYMMDD` is older than 30 days for example to make a list of tasks to create new dated directory and do the backup itself  (synchronize method might be good?).

How can I get this ?

Steps to get :

- find last backup date
- find current date
- arithmetic difference between them
- apply that difference as a when statement in a task from the yaml file

```yaml
 - name: Check the last backup date                                                                                                                                                          
    shell: |                                                                                                                                                                                  
      #or find module                                                                                
    register: lastone
                                                                                                                                                                        
  - name: Get current date for arithmetics                                                                                                                                                    
    shell: |                                                                                                                                                                                  
      echo $(date +%s)                                                                                                                                                                        
    register: currentdate                                                                                                                                                                     

  - name: Find ideal path to create new backup if last one is too old                                                                                                                         
    # define & create new directory if currentdate - lastone is over a numeric value (suffisant difference)                                                                                                                                                                            
    when: "{{ currentdate | int - lastone | int }}" > 40000
```

Here I've finished to get a dummy start of solution pig style for testing:

```yaml
---                                                                                                                                                                                           
- hosts: localhost                                                                                                                                                                            
  become: true                                                                                                                                                                                
  become_method: sudo                                                                                                                                                                         
  become_user: francois                                                                                                                                                                       

  tasks:                                                                                                                                                                                      

  - name: Check the last backup date                                                                                                                                                          
    shell: |                                                                                                                                                                                  
      date +%s -r $(find /mnt{1,2,3}/ -type d -name "backup.*[0-9]" 2> /dev/null | sort | tail -1)                                                                                            
    args:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      executable: /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                   
    register: lastone                                                                                                                                                                         

  - name: Get current date for arithmetics                                                                                                                                                    
    shell: |                                                                                                                                                                                  
      date +%s                                                                                                                                                                                
    register: currentdate                                                                                                                                                                     

  - set_fact:                                                                                                                                                                                 
      difference: "{{ currentdate.stdout | int - lastone.stdout | int }}"                                                                                                                   

  - name: Find ideal path to create new backup if last one is too old                                                                                                                         
    shell: |                                                                                                                                                                                  
      find /mnt{1,2,3}/ -type d -name "backup.*[0-9]" 2> /dev/null | sort -n | tail -1 | sed "s/\.[0-9].*/\.$(date +%Y%m%d)/"                                                                 
    args:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      executable: /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                   
    register: rep                                                                                                                                                                             
    when:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      - difference | int > 4000                                                                                                                                                               

  - name: Create path                                                                                                                                                                         
    file:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      path: "{{ rep.stdout }}"                                                                                                                                                                
      state: directory                                                                                                                                                                        
      mode: "0755"                                                                                                                                                                            
    when:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      - rep is defined                                                                                                                                                                        
      - difference | int > 4000
```

That results well creating the `backup.20210630` directory wherever it is mounted behind `/mnt1` or `2` or `3` (*here 3*).

```
francois@zaphod:~/GITLAB/dev/dev_ansible_serviceatonce$ ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1 ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts roles/filebackup/filebackup.yaml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check the last backup date] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Get current date for arithmetics] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [find ideal path to create new backup if last one is too old] ***************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [create path] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

francois@zaphod:~/GITLAB/dev/dev_ansible_serviceatonce$ ls -d /mnt3/backup.202106*
/mnt3/backup.20210604  /mnt3/backup.20210610  /mnt3/backup.20210615  /mnt3/backup.20210621  /mnt3/backup.20210629  /mnt3/backup.20210630
francois@zaphod:~/GITLAB/dev/dev_ansible_serviceatonce$
```

Comment: Look into the `stat` module.

Comment: I did but it doesn't include such a functionnality

Comment: It does - look at the `Return` section. It returns `atime`, `ctime` and `mtime`.

Comment: yes but there is no difference beetween x and y  ...

Comment: What do you mean by x and y? Where is this stated in your question? Consider editing it and making it more clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: difference between currentdate & last backup date found  ; I was hoping  this was really clear enough :)

Comment: What do you want to compare? Is it the '[acm]time' attribute or is it the suffix 'YYYYMMDD '? Make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your main question

> *How to trigger an Ansible task only if concerned directories are old enough? ... My goal is if `backup.YYYYMMDD` is older than 30days ...*

I've setup a small test with directories according the given naming convention

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Jan  2 00:00 backup.20220102
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Jan  9 00:00 backup.20220109
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Jan 16 00:00 backup.20220116
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Jan 23 00:00 backup.20220123
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Jan 30 00:00 backup.20220130
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group     4096 Feb  6 00:00 backup.20220206
```

as well with [changing the `mtime` of the directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385370/) via `touch -t YYMMDDHHMM.SS backup.YYYYMMDD`.

```
$ stat backup.20220102/
  File: ‘backup.20220102/’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
...
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (1234/user)   Gid: (1234/group)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Change: 2022-02-06 09:00:00.000000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

It will be possible to compare based on the `[am]time` attribute or the name suffix `YYYYMMDD`. You could start with the [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) module.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Find directories older than 30 days
    find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
      file_type: directory
      age: 30d
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item[0] }}"
    loop:
      - "{{ result.files | flatten(levels=1) }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: yes
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

And than [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over the result [Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and [Filter data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html). You may also have a look into the `stat` module to [Retrieve file or file system status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html).

To "find" your current date you may have a look into [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts).

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

since it is usually gathered already.

```yaml
TASK [Show Gathered Facts] ******
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
    ...
    date_time:
      date: '2022-02-06'
      day: '06'
      epoch: '1644142041'
      hour: '11'
      iso8601: '2022-02-06T10:07:21Z'
      iso8601_basic: 20220206T110721823347
      iso8601_basic_short: 20220206T110721
      iso8601_micro: '2022-02-06T10:07:21.823347Z'
      minute: '07'
      month: '02'
      second: '21'
      time: '11:07:21'
      tz: CET
      tz_offset: '+0100'
      weekday: Sunday
      weekday_number: '0'
      weeknumber: '05'
      year: '2022'
    ...
```

You can [Grouping tasks with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) based on [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts).